# How do I create a timer on netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

For my maze project, I want to create a monitor button that keeps track of how long it takes for the turtle to get from start to finish.  How would I code for the timer?

Comment: Do you want to measure ticks or moves? for example a turtle might not move and only change direction if faced a wall but it will count as a tick. You can simply add a move-count varibel to turtles and when you use fd 1 increase it by 1

Comment: If you mean real time Stephen already pointed you to the timer

Answer (score 2):

Check out `reset-timer` and `timer` and in the docs. During maze setup, do a `reset-timer`. During the running of maze you can check on elapsed time with `timer`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how many patches passed in moving to the target, you can use following:

```
turtles-own [target move-counter]

 to Your-Move-Function
      let t target 
      face min-one-of all-possible-moves [distance t]
      fd 1
      set move-counter move-counter + 1
    end
```