# How to add to score after a turtle dies

Tags: netlogo

So my go procedure right now is

```
to Go
  ask turtles with [is-moving?]

  [
    if any? other turtles-here [
      ask other turtles-here [
        die
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

(is-moving? is just a turtles-own variable to specify the only turtle that i want to move)

I wanted to add 5 points to the score everytime it went through the go procedure and a turtle died.  I already set a global variable to score.  Thanks!

Comment: Try formatting your code with four spaces before each line of code.  It is almost impossible to read as it is.

Comment: Why do turtles got to die man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  score is global variable just add `set score Score + 5`

```
to Go
  ask turtles with [is-moving?]

  [
    if any? other turtles-here [

      ask other turtles-here [
 set score Score + 5
        die

      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

**Update:**

I think you dont need to multiply it since all turtles will update the score value ! (my mistake! )To monitor Score :

[image]

Comment: what should I write under reporter when I add the monitor button?

Comment: If you mean you want to see Score in monitor just add a new monitor to interface and write the variable name (Score) in that monitor

Comment: For some reason the scores not adding on... I did exactly as said

Comment: ohhh , ok I will check it but you can try adding set score Score + 5   just one line before die!

Comment: okay, sorry to bother again but how do you set the ticks to time how long it takes to get through the maze?

Comment: you can use a turtle-own [movement-count] and whenver turtle makes a move increase the movement-count by 1

Comment: by How long do you mean real time or steps?

Comment: um I'm trying to do steps

Comment: If its steps you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082953/how-do-i-create-a-timer-on-netlogo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45329/discussion-between-marzy-and-user3188146)