# Please show me some samples about coding of timer with how it work on NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am considering a code to stop Turtle on the patch of the specified color with the specified period of time. However, it still can not succeed. Maybe timer is useful. Please give me some samples about coding of timer with how it work on NetLogo.

The following URLs are similar questions, but there are few concrete code examples.

[How do I create a timer on netlogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082953/how-do-i-create-a-timer-on-netlogo)

Comment: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting some downvotes because it's a little too open ended of a question and isn't very clear.

You can make a timer by creating a global

```
globals [timer]
```

and each tick, increase it during the go command

```
to go
*blah blah blah all you're other stuff*

set timer timer + 1
tick
end
```

Just modify that to you're needs. If you have more trouble, come back with a specific answer and a simplified snippet of you're problematic code.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I will try this code on my model later.